# Как выбрать нужные метки на графике matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Помогите пожалуйста, не понимаю как сделать нужные мне метки по пикам моего графика.
Мой код:

```
dis1 = dis['район']
District1 = dis['count']
plt.plot(dis1, District1, marker = "o", c = "salmon",)
plt.grid ()
plt.rcParams ['figure.figsize'] = [25, 15]
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
```

Такой график получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сделать так, что бы пиковые значения были написаны (можно сделать, например, от 50 на оси y?), А другие нет (скрыты или удалены я не знаю как действовать тут).

Что должно быть получиться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведите в вопросе исходные данные (датафрейм), можно ссылкой на файл csv.

Comment: как я понимаю, вам нужны не локальные максимумы, а значения выше определенной величины.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19tF05sC4yD5uHXHpfBtbd2sS4EwkkSlQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: можно сделать как выше определенной величины так и локальные максимумы, для развития и понимания в будущем как это делается)

Comment: Но в этой задаче наверное лучше будет сделать выше определенной величины

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое решение - оставить только нужные вам метки:

```
dis1 = dis['district']
District1 = dis['count']

plt.plot(dis1, District1, marker = "o", c = "salmon",)
plt.grid()
plt.rcParams ['figure.figsize'] = [25, 15]
labels = dis[dis["count"]>=50]
plt.xticks(labels.index, labels["district"], rotation = 90)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!